# what is the difference between cascading and chaining

Tags: c#, java, javascript, jquery

I just find from a forum about cascade. The question was what does cascading means in poo. I tried to find to google the answer, also tried to find some other stackoverflow threads about if but I couldn't. I just find this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading

I know what is chaining, I used it, most in javascript, jquery and other languages, but I coundn't understand the difference between chaining and cascading. Can anybody help me? Or can anybody provide some useful links regarding to this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading#Comparison_with_method_chaining

Comment: Yes, I mean oop, sorry

Answer (score 5):

The definition is pretty clear on the Wikipedia page you linked:

> Given a method call a.b(), after executing the call, method cascading evaluates this expression to the left object a (with its new value, if mutated), while method chaining evaluates this expression to the right object.

This means that, `a.b()` returns a mutated `a` instance with method cascading. `a.b()` returns something different from `b()` with method chaining.

So, this is method cascading:

```
class YourClass {
    public YourClass b() {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }

    public YourClass c() {
        // do stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

..which allows: `yourClass.b().c();`.

..and this is method chaining:

```
class YourClass {
    public SomeOtherObject b() {
        // do stuff
        return new SomeOtherObject(this);
    }
}

class SomeOtherObject {
    private YourClass _owner;

    public SomeOtherObject(YourClass owner) {
        _owner = owner;
    }

    public void c_onOtherObject() {
    }
}
```

..which allows: `yourClass.b().c_onOtherObject();`.

EDIT: I rolled back my previous edit. It appears the above is correct and the terms aren't flipped incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Chaining is where you return the result of the method call to be used in the next call.

c#

```
Enumerable.Range(0,10).Skip(1).Aggregate(myList.First(),(result,listItem) => result += listItem));
//results in 45 being returned
```

Cascading can be implemented by using chaining when `this` is returned (making it sometimes tricky to differentiate between the two). jQuery does this.

jquery

```
$("#myId").css("background-color","blue").fadeIn().fadeOut();
//results in $("#myId") being returned
```

Comment: Mmm.. we appear to have flipped definitions. I read that Wikipedia article differently. I personally have always referred to it as "chaining".

Comment: @KevinB I was referring to the Wikipedia article. I think "cascading" sounds more like stepping down through a hierarchy.. which means the Wikipedia article is wrong.. and Travis is right.

Comment: I agree, that does look a bit off...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - My explanation was not clear enough at first, I do not think you were incorrect in your post. Please see my edit

Comment: the explanation on the methodChaning page is a little more in-depth: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: @KevinB - Yes that page does seem to do a better job of it.

Comment: Wow.. what do you know.. the Wikipedia article was correct. It sounds so odd...  :/

Comment: *"since chaining is widely implemented in object-oriented languages while cascading isn't, this form of "cascading-by-chaining by returning this" is often referred to simply as "chaining"."* hahaha.

Comment: So cascading is just a particular way of chaining, the diference is that cascading needs to return this. Very interesting...