# How do you call this language construct / technique in C#?

Tags: c#

I am reading a C# code from some one else, and I found this line:

**RE-EDITED:** (It was missing the sprite object and one extra parameter)

```
Foo1.move(sprite, new Vector3(1.7f, 1.7f, 1.7f), 5f).setColor(myRGB);
```

The method **.setColor()** is not part of Foo1 class, it is from another class, so my question is regarding how is possible to call this method at the end of the method **.move()**?

The Foo1 class has this declaration:

```
public class Foo1 : MonoBehaviour {...}
```

and the class that contains the .setColor() method has this declaration:

```
public class ObjectProperties {...}
```

Is this technique usual in C#? and how is it called?

Comment: `The method .setColor() is not part of Foo1 class` Does `move` return a `Foo1`, because unless it does, that's irrelevant.  What matters is if `setColor` is a method in whatever type `move` returns.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a technical term, but I would call it method chaining. It's calling a method on the object that the previous method returned, and is a very common technique, especially in LINQ.

Comment: This line is incomplete. It has 3 closing brackets and only 2 opening. Probably part of the expression was in the previous line.

Comment: This is common in any C derived language, if a function returns a class or struct (or an object in the concrete C# case) you can then add "." and access the object properties/functions.

Comment: I've heard this pattern referred to by many names, such as Method Chaining, Method Cascading, and Fluent Interface. It is fairly popular. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @BradleyUffner Those are terms for objects whose methods return the instance you called the method on.  We know for a fact that that's *not* going on here, so that *isn't* applicable here.

Comment: Yep, this is **method chaining**. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining.

Comment: @Servy: Agreed that method chaining is usually seen in cases where all methods return the same object on which they were invoked -- if the Wikipedia article I linked to is correct, then this is only a special form of method chaining known as method cascading; see also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412412/what-is-the-diference-between-cascading-and-chaining

Comment: @stakx Two of the three terms that he claimed were equivalent are certainly not applicable here, including the only one that was actually defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assumption

In order to answer this question (I should not have withdrawed my close vote!!! The question lacks essential information) I assume the following:

```
public class Foo1{
     Foo1 move(...);
}

public class ObjectProperties{
      static Foo1/void setColor(this Foo1); //magic explained later
}
```

The name of the second class suggests this set up

## Answer

It is called [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), which is just **synctactic sugar** for **static helper method**

An extension method allows a third-party developer to add a methods to a class developed by someone else without the need to use inheritance.

Your clever coworker found a way to move a `Foo1` on the screen which was not written by the original developer. Instead of pleasing the developer to add the new function to the class (with all the IP/patent issues and by having to wait for next release), your coworker did all this in house.

He wrote

```
public static class ObjectProperties {

      public static [something] setColor(this Foo1 foo, Object rgb){
      }

}
```

The above, with the exception of the `this` modifier to be discussed, is a legal static helper method that can be used in older C# version and Java and any other OO language. It can access Foo's public members and so on.

What makes C# cool is that you will be able to call this method **like if it was a real method of Foo1**, thus *extending* the class with a new method

## It's all sugar, baby

Don't be fooled. There is no magic, there is no *hacking*, there is no Jon Skeet refactoring the obfuscated DLL from which Foo1 comes.

The compiler will just **translate** your call to

```
ObjectProperties.move(Foo1.move(sprite, new Vector3(1.7f, 1.7f, 1.7f), 5f),myRgb);
```

Nothing else

Answer (score 2):

`setColor` could be an extension method, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx or move() is just returning an object that has a `setColor` method. Sometimes called fluent interface.

Comment: It can be or maybe it isn't. Syntactically, an extension method is indistinguishable from a normal one.

Answer (score 1):

Find out what Foo1.move() returns. It should return a class that has the setColor method as @Servy said.